# Mysql- SQL profiling missing 'Sending data' phase

Tags: mysql, sql, profiling

I was profiling a query that returns very less data: SELECT MAX(LastModTime) FROM Orders;. But the profiling information did not show any time spent in 'Sending data'. My understanding is it does send the 1 row across to the client, so we must see that phase in the profiling as well?

```
mysql> show profile for query 1;
+----------------------+----------+
| Status               | Duration |
+----------------------+----------+
| starting             | 0.000058 |
| checking permissions | 0.000008 |
| Opening tables       | 0.000021 |
| init                 | 0.000022 |
| System lock          | 0.000007 |
| optimizing           | 0.000056 |
| executing            | 0.000009 |
| end                  | 0.000003 |
| query end            | 0.000006 |
| closing tables       | 0.000007 |
| freeing items        | 0.000039 |    
| cleaning up          | 0.000004 |
+----------------------+----------+
12 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```